# Swift: View Controller crashes after database updates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, updates

I am trying to make an RSS reader, it has a database which updates every 30 minutes or so (I currently have it on 10 seconds for testing), when you select a set of Feeds you want to look at, it takes them from the database and puts them into an array called feedItems. This array is only modified in viewDidLoad to copy it from the database and when the cell is configured to see if that particular post has been deleted or not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = theTitle
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Feed")
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Feed] {
        for f: Feed in fetchResults{
            if f.category == theUrl{

                feedItems.append(f)
            }
        }

        feedItems.sort({ self.getFeedId($0.url).toInt() > self.getFeedId($1.url).toInt() })
    }

    if deletedFeeds.count > 10000 {
        deletedFeeds = []
    }
}
```

cell configuration:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as Feed
    // Configure the cell...
    if contains(deletedFeeds, getFeedId(item.url)){
    feedItems.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }else{
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.summary
    }
    return cell
}
```

The problem is the fact that if the database(It is a Core Data database and updates on a separate thread) updates while you are in the tableViewController that holds all the posts, all of the objects for every item in the array feedItems becomes nil, which causes the program to crash if you click on a cell or scroll down the tableview because the url for every cell is nil. I don't know why this happens because I did not write anything that is supposed to update the feedItems array from the database other than in the viewDidLoad. If I exit the tableViewController controller and navigate back to it, it updates fine. Why does every object in the array become nil if I stay in the tableViewController when it updates and how can I fix it so that it updates correctly while I am still in that tableViewController?

Comment: You may be breaking one of the rules on multithreaded CoreData somewhere.  Have you read up on [how to handle multithreaded core data](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131)?

Comment: Can you notify the view controller with the table to reload it's data after core data has been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to copy Core Data objects into an array is problematic. The problem you run in is emblematic. There are far better ways to solve this.

You need to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. It optimizes the display of Core Data entities in a table view both for performance and memory. You can implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to update the table view as the data changes.

To get started, create a new project (Master-Detail, check "Core Data") and examine the MasterViewController. Just follow this pattern.

Comment: I used a NSFetchedResultsController and it works now but is it really necessary to use a Master-Detail View Controller? Will it have any effect on the performance or efficiency of the application?

Comment: FRC will certainly improve performance and memory management - significantly!